# How to comment out a line in docstrip?

Tags: comments, docstrip

While using docstrip to write a documented package, I have difficulties in commenting lines of the doc. Here is my minimal `test.dtx`

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% ABC % DEF
```

I would like the final `DEF` to be commented out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside `\DocInput` the comment character is `^^A`:

```latex
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% ABC ^^A DEF
```